# Пагинация при query_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, cms, pagination

Сайт на Wordpress. Есть код:

```
<?php 

query_posts("cat=18");
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    get_template_part( "books-cat");
endwhile;

?>

<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?>
```

На странице выводятся посты и пагинация. Эта пагинация не работает, а именно при переходе на вторую страницу, адрес меняется, а посты выводятся те же, т.е. с первой страницы.

Как сделать, чтобы пагинация заработала?

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать чтобы пагинация заработала?

Выкинуть `query_posts` как устаревший и потенциально опасный, а использовать [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query) или [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts).

См. доп на русском [wp_query](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query), [get_posts](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts).

Comment: Окей, поменял только что на wp_query. Но проблема сохранилась

Comment: Если в том коде  просто сменить query_posts на  wp_query, но врядли что-то получиться. См на вп-кама - там и про пагинацю написано и примеры даны. И вообще в коде нет вывода контента, но подключение темплейта.. странная какая-то задумка.